# Recycle app pool in a ASP.NET web request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to recycle the application pool of an ASP.NET application in a http request received to the application? I would like to have a method the recycle the application pool easily without having to login to the machine.

Comment: Throw SO and get app domain recycled :) Or you actually need app pool recycle? (possible too, just need permissions sorted out).

Comment: @HashPsi No! Your web app should never have permission to modify web.config. If it does, minor vulnerabilities in your site could balloon into a full server compromise far too easily.

Answer (score 3):

A usual way to restart an ASP.NET application is calling:

```
HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
```

So place the call into your page or handler.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to recycle app pool

```
 Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
 process.Kill(); // This will kill your worker process
```

OR

```
 HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain(); // Kill app domain. Next request will restart the app domain
```

OR
Programatically touch your web.config and that should also trigger app recycle